# How do I assign a particular post to a particular page in Wordpress?

Tags: theme-development

I have created a separate page called `service.php` with following code

```
<?php /* Template Name: services */ ?>
......//code
......
```

So the above page now acts as separate static page.
Now I want to assign a particular post for this service page in WordPress.

Is it possible to do that?

Kindly advise me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Pages can have templates, but not posts. You have [created a custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates). There is no out-of-the-box way to have a post template, but there is a highly rated plugin called [Custom Post Template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/) that will do what I think you want to do.